# Multiple connections with aptitude-faster downloads

Tags: bash, download, debian, apt-get, aptitude

I'm wondering whether there is a way to establish multiple connections with aptitude with the aim of increasing download speed. Since I couldn't find such a functionality in aptitude man page (in my limited knowledge), I would rephrase my question: Is there a way to use another download manager that can use multiple connections and pass the downloaded package to aptitude?

I know that aptitude can install packages from local disk, however when there are lots of dependencies it would be nice to integrate a download manager (such as aria2 with several connections) into aptitude so that the main packages and dependencies could be installed without me downloading each one with aria2 and then pass it to aptitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `apt-fast` I guess.

Here is a nice description and tutorial: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/speed-up-apt-get-downloads-with-apt.html